# Excel Sum instances of an item in a column until a different column variable is met

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

What I'm trying to accomplish is a little complicated to explain:

There is a formula that inserts an integer into Columns `B` or `C` depending on the values of other columns (not shown here).

What I want to do it place a sum of the items in column `B` where the criteria are:

1. Items in column `B` have a value of 1

and

2. The range that is counted are all items between `Type A` and `Type A` (in the image below `B2:B13`)

The sum should be placed in the cell in line with the instance of `Type A` being used for the range.

So Below I want the sum of items in column `B` that are occur in rows `B3:B13` and have that number placed in `B2`.
Then the same for `B15:B24` and the result placed in `B14`, and so on...
The test in column `A` that will be the trigger will remain consistent as it is auto-generated.

Then the same would happen in column `C` (which I'm assuming I can just use the same formula just change the column references)

[image: Image to use as a sample]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Place this formula in `B2`:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(OFFSET(B3,0,0,MATCH($A2,$A3:$A1000,0)-1,1)),SUM(B3:B1000))
```

Then filter on all rows with `Type A` and copy from B2 for all the visible cells.

The `IFERROR` is only for the last `Type A` (with no `Type A` underneath it. Then it will just sum the remaining rows underneath. Also, adjust the `1000` if needed.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm trying to get the process to automate so that I don't have to filter each time.

Comment: if you are trying to get automation (VBA), you'll need to post the coding attempts you've tried and where it's gone wrong, then someone will help you fix it